# Проблема с позиционированием элементов, лишние отступы

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с тем, что вылезают лишние отступы, элементы пляшут на странице. На первом скрине видно, что происходит с текстом, при равном коде для блоков. Причем происходит не только с текстом но и с изображениями, на том же скрине видно, что линия под блоком уходит вниз намного ниже установленного padding верхнего элемента. На втором скрине подобный случай, а именно не понятный отступ между блоками, которые должны прижиматься друг к другу. Стили сбрасываю с помощью [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Еще вопрос: как сделать так чтобы текст был заданной размерности, т.е задаю размер тексту, проверяю в консоле разработчика область(высота строки) у текста все равно больше, `line-height` менял на в normalize на 1, не помогло.[image: текст пляшет][image: лишние отступы]

```css
.services {
  height: 373px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.service_item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 31px;
}

.services>.service_item:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.img_icon {
  /*padding-bottom: 30px;*/
}

.service_name {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #555555;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px
}

.service_name:hover {
  color: rgb(198, 179, 153);
}

.service_description {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  padding-bottom: 33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <div class="service_item">
    <img class="img_icon" src="../Waxom/icons/pencil.png" alt="pencil.png">
    <p class="service_name">Web App Design</p>
    <p class="service_description">Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis<br>eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet<br>doming id quod mazim.</p>
    <img src="icons/line-service.png" alt="line">
  </div>
  <div class="service_item">
    <img class="img_icon" src="../Waxom/icons/paper.png" alt="paper.png">
    <p class="service_name">Development</p>
    <p class="service_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing<br>elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod<br>tincidunt ut laoreet.</p>
    <img src="icons/line-service.png" alt="line">
  </div>
  <div class="service_item">
    <img class="img_icon" src="../Waxom/icons/gear.png" alt="gear.png">
    <p class="service_name">Customization</p>
    <p class="service_description">Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis<br>eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet<br>doming id quod mazim.</p>
    <img src="icons/line-service.png" alt="line">
  </div>
  <div class="service_item">
    <img class="img_icon" src="../Waxom/icons/folder.png" alt="folder.png">
    <p class="service_name">Marketing</p>
    <p class="service_description">Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis<br>eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet<br>doming id quod mazim.</p>
    <img src="icons/line-service.png" alt="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. У блока .services стоит свойство align-items: center; , из-за этого .service_item выравниваются по вертикали друг относительно друга (скорее всего у вас иконки разной высоты)
2. У параграфа есть дефолтный марджин

Comment: 1. Как в таком случае выровнять блоки чтобы текст был на одной высоте?
2. Этот дефолтный маржин можно убрать? Потому что с psd беру одни расстояния, на верстке получается другое.
3. Линии на первом скрине я так понимаю тоже поплыли из-за иконок?
4. Проблема этих заплывов мне кажется системна, потому что между блоками вылезают непонятные пиксели, как на втором скрине

Comment: Для иконок сделайте обертку и задайте ей хардовую высоту, а высоту картинок ограничите в 100%. По поводу параграфов, просто обнулите отступ в свои стилях. Там где скрин с рукой - укажие картинке dispaly:block; (больше сказать трудно так как верстка в вопросе не идентичная той что у вас на сайте)

Comment: В том то и дело что помимо Normalize до кучи и в стилях прописывал margin и padding=0 текст имеет дополнительные области, т.е не обрезается строго по границам. Что касается по скрину с рукой display не помог, изображение изначально позиционировано относительно родительского блока со значением bottom:0 но как видно что результатов это не дало

Comment: Есть подобный блок как на первом скрине с иконкой тексто под ним и линей с самого низа, там нижняя линия так же тонет ниже заданного уровня, при том что иконки имеют одинаковую размерность, текст соответственно тоже